# Make textarea fill table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I know, there are similar questions on SO, but the answers didn't seem to work for me. My table has got a cell that fills multiple rows, and I want the textarea to fill the whole cell. The code that I've found doesn't work for height.

**CSS**

```
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    resize: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* <=iOS4, <= Android  2.3 */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* FF1+ */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Chrome, IE8, Opera, Safari 5.1*/
}
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/4nkwhLj5/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can make it work by adding `position: relative` to the td, and `position: absolute` to the textarea.

This is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/stefarossi/5Lwhg7mb/2/

Hope you can find this useful.

Comment: I never understand why this works. 
could you elaborate why absolute and relative ?

Comment: I ended up with using a fixed row number in my application, but this does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a table display, the 100% will only account for the parent row.  You will need to be more specific on the height setting and add the height of the table to the textarea, in this case

```
height: 126px
```

See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4nkwhLj5/1/

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution for the % height, you need to precise the size with for example pixel size (for example 300px) although I would use rows and cols in this situation:

```
<textarea cols="15" rows="10"></textarea>
```

For more info about columns and rows size: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_rows.asp)